# TCPDF generation: image flows into next column when too high

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I am currently in the process of generating a report type of a pdf where several articles are merged into a given layout. A few days ago, I had to change the structure of the pdf so that the article text would be divided into three separate columns.

The problem I'm facing is that, once you insert an image into the html and the image is too high to fit into, for example, the first column, it's put into the second column as it should be, but due to some weird spacing or something different, it's offset to the right so that half of the image is shoved into the following column:

[image: PDF problem showcase]

The way I'm generating the Html for the PDF to be generated on is rather simple:

```
// add source to article
$htmlString  = '<p style="font-size: 17px;">' . $valVal['source'] . ' vom ' . $valVal['date'] . '</p>';

// add title to article
$htmlString .= '<p style="font-size: 22px; text-align: left;">' . $valVal['title'] . '</p>';

// Add subtitle to article
if ($valVal['subtitle'] != '' && $valVal['subtitle'] != null) {
    $htmlString .= '<p style="font-size: 13px; text-align: justify; padding: 0; margin: 0; font-weight: bold;">' . $valVal['subtitle'] . '</p>';
}

$this->pdf->writeHtml($htmlString . '<p><br></p>', true, false, false, false, '');
$htmlString = '';

$this->pdf->setEqualColumns(3, 57);  // KEY PART -  number of cols and width
$this->pdf->selectColumn(); // select proper column

// Add summary
if ($valVal['summary'] != '' && $valVal['summary'] != null) {
    $htmlString .= '<p style="font-size: 13px;">Zusammenfassung:</p>';
    $htmlString .= '<div class="article-summary" style="font-size: 13px; text-align: justify; padding-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">';

    // if there are image captions, style them
    if(preg_match("/(\<figcaption.*\>)(.*)(\<\/figcaption\>)/", $valVal['summary'])) {
        $valVal['summary'] = preg_replace("/(\<figcaption.*\>)(.*)(\<\/figcaption\>)/", '$1<div style="background-color: #ffffff; font-size: 9px;">$2</div>$3', $valVal['summary']);
        $valVal['summary'] = preg_replace("/<img([\w\W]+?)(\/|)>/", '<div style="text-align:center;">$0</div>', $valVal['summary']);
    }

    $htmlString .= $valVal['summary'];

    $htmlString .= '</div>';
}

// build html string for the article's text
$htmlString .= '<p style="font-size: 13px; text-align: justify;">';

// if there are image captions, style them
if(preg_match("/(\<figcaption.*\>)(.*)(\<\/figcaption\>)/", $valVal['excerpt'])) {
    $valVal['excerpt'] = preg_replace("/(\<figcaption.*\>)(.*)(\<\/figcaption\>)/", '$1<div style="background-color: #ffffff; font-size: 9px;">$2</div>$3', $valVal['excerpt']);
    $valVal['excerpt'] = preg_replace("/<img([\w\W]+?)(\/|)>/", '<div style="text-align:center;">$0</div>', $valVal['excerpt']);
}

$htmlString .= $valVal['excerpt'];
$htmlString .= '</p>';

$this->writeHyphenatedHtml($htmlString); // the function uses the php library "Syllable" and then inserts the text via "WriteHtml" - this is not the issue, I've tested without the hyphenation
```

Has anyone had a related problem and knows how I could improve this?

Edit: the generated html of the specific part looks like this - ignore the html entities please:

```
<p>&#8222;AC/DC
   bietet sich doch eigentlich fürs Klavier an&#8220;, kündigt Rüth im vollbesetzten Kammermusiksaal nach
   knapp 100 überraschenden Konzertminuten die letzte Zugabe an.
   &#8222;Oder Löwenzahn&#8220;
   ergänzt ihre Bühnenkollegin Ming mit
   koreanischen Wurzeln. Sie eröffnen
   mit Johann Sebastian Bachs
   &#8222;Toccata&#8220; und treiben
   sich gegenseitig an ihren Flügeln sitzend in den HardrockRhythmus der
   australischen Rockband hinein.
   &#8222;Thunderstruck&#8220; von
   AC/DC.
</p>
<figure id="attachment_620" style="width: 201px"
   class="wp-caption alignnone">
   <div
      style="text-align:center;"><img
      class="wp-image-620 size-full" src="
      http://127.0.0.1/_project/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/bild-2.jpg"
      alt="" width="201" height="245"
      /></div>
   <figcaption class="wp-caption-text">
      <div style="background-color: #ffffff; font-size: 9px;">Die beiden
         Musikerinnen nach der Show. (c)
         Spiegel online
      </div>
   </figcaption>
</figure>
<p> Die beiden Musikerinnen spielen im Sitzen, im Stehen und im Liegen. Sie zupfen die
   Saiten der beiden Flügel, sie benutzen sie als Percussions-Instrument
   oder einfach nur als Ablage für ihre
</p>
```

Comment: Does it show correctly if you let the _browser_ display the HTML you are assembling there?

Comment: Yes, outputting the html to a page shows the image correctly - however, it's not separated into three columns there, because that's not something the browser handles, as it's just a marker vor TCPDF, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `<div style="text-align:center;">` you have wrapping your images is the problem. I'm assuming this is here to ensure center alignment when you have an image that doesn't span the entire width of the column. Changing `text-alignment` doesn't change the values fed to `Image` internally so it's some combination of current layout/parser state and the column breaking handling. Debugging TCPDF state at this point is a bit beyond my ability.

However, I do have a workaround: Table support is a little more robust in TCPDF, so instead of using a div to perform this center alignment, use a single-cell `table`.  That is: `<table width="100%"><tbody><tr><td align="center"><!--Image tag here--></td></tr></tbody></table>`

Here's the image formatting code I used to produce the output in the screenshot below:

```
$valVal['excerpt'] = preg_replace("/<img([\w\W]+?)(\/|)>/", '<table width="100%"><tbody><tr><td align="center">$0</td></tr></tbody></table>', $valVal['excerpt']);
//I'm wrapping any image tag here. 
$valVal['excerpt'] = str_replace('<figcaption', '<div style="font-size: 9px;" ', $valVal['excerpt']);
$valVal['excerpt'] = str_replace('</figcaption', '</div', $valVal['excerpt']);
//figcaption not supported. Replacing to preserve proper text placement.
```

*Note:* TCPDF removes figcaption and figure from the input HTML, so I got lazy and just replaced figcaption with divs. In testing I found that by aligning your images with a table, your captions *MUST BE WRAPPED BY A SUPPORTED BLOCK-LEVEL TAG* or the caption text will not appear in the column.

[image: Sample with correctly working image placement]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such an elaborate answer and test this edge case for me! I find it weird how the div seems to be wider than a column, but I know about the "low compatibility" of TCPDF. I've adapted my code to match your given example, and it works like a charm. Furthermore, it moved the picture caption up just below the image, which is just what I needed as well. Again, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, no problem. Interestingly, the div was actually the correct size, but it was offsetting the image correspondent to the image's width when the `Image` call resulted in a column break. So, for example, a full width image would straddle the div's right border. Handling the column break seemed to throw off the centering calculations.